# Struggling with a pivot query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, pivot

I use a Linq-2-Sql at the moment in order to perform a fairly complicated query. It is however very inefficient and results in multiple round trips being made to the server.

Using some joins I have managed to get the data into a format like this:

```
Sensor -- Timestamp        -- Value
A      -- 12/02/2013 09:00 -- 10.4
A      -- 12/02/2013 10:00 -- 10.3
A      -- 12/02/2013 11:00 -- 10.1
B      -- 12/02/2013 09:00 -- 15.3
B      -- 12/02/2013 10:00 -- 16.4
B      -- 12/02/2013 11:00 -- 15.4
```

I desire this in an output like

```
TimeStamp        -- SensorA -- SensorB
12/02/2013 09:00 -- 10.4    -- 15.3
12/02/2013 10:00 -- 10.3    -- 16.4
12/02/2013 11:00 -- 10.1    -- 15.4
```

I am guessing I need a dynamic pivot? Can anybody help point me in the right direction?

**EDIT** - Obviously there are more than the 2 sensors...ideally I need this to be able to scale out in terms of columns. I don't even know if SQL Server can do this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to transform the data.

If you have a limited number of `Sensor` values, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select *
from
(
  select sensor, timestamp, value
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for sensor in (A, B)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5abdbb/1)

But if the values are unknown then you will want to implement dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Sensor) 
                    from yourtable  -- table containing Sensor values
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT timestamp, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select sensor, timestamp, value
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for sensor in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5abdbb/3)

Both will give the result:

```
|           TIMESTAMP |    A |    B |
-------------------------------------
| 2013-12-02 09:00:00 | 10.4 | 15.3 |
| 2013-12-02 10:00:00 | 10.3 | 16.4 |
| 2013-12-02 11:00:00 | 10.1 | 15.4 |
```

*Note, you will replace the `yourtable` with your current query.*

Edit #1, if you want to filter by date, you could use the following dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime

set @startdate = '2013-12-01'
set @enddate = '2013-12-03'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Sensor) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT timestamp, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select sensor, timestamp, value
                from yourtable
                where timestamp >= '''+convert(varchar(10), @startdate, 120)+'''
                  and timestamp <= '''+convert(varchar(10), @enddate, 120)+'''
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for sensor in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5abdbb/9)

Comment: Hi @bluefeet, thanks for your help so far, I will be trying this now.

Comment: I have made a couple of changes to fit with my real world code, and it seems to be working fairly well. I have added an ORDER BY field at the end of the pivot since my data is not necessaries in the right order to begin with. Only thing I am left to understand is how I can add a date filter to this? i.e. how can I specify only data for certain date? When I try it not parse because I can't work out how to add date parameter to query.

Comment: Nevermind I think I just need to CONVERT it first. Many thanks. Answer accepted.

Comment: @KingCronus sorry for the delay, you will just need to convert the date to a string to be added to the sql string.  I have updated my answer with an example.